# Error: Caused By: No valid license for plugin while using plsql plugin with Sonar 3.6.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have following configuration

- Java 64 bit 1.6_30
- Sonar 3.6.1
- Oracle 11g
- PL/SQL plug in 2.4 , updated via Update center of Sonarqube
- Sonnar-runner 2.2.2

While I am trying to analyse PL/SQL codebase by running sonar-runner , it throws "Error: Caused by: No valid license for plugin"

PL/SQL plugin shows license type is "commercial"

Can anyone explain the issue and provide a solution for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SonarQube PL/SQL plugin is a commercial product, so you need to buy a license if you want to use it.

Please visit [the home page of this plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/) for more information.

Comment: the page says Enterprise: included. What does included mean?

Comment: This means that if you've purchased an Enterprise or Ultimate Edition, then you don't have to add extra money to get this plugin - it's included in the edition.